# How can I change the language of bs-datepicker

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I am developing a web service. But I do not know how to set the language of bs-datepicker with Angularjs. It is in English, but I want to change this to 'kr'. What should I do?

```
<input type="text" class="form-control 
text-center"data-date-format="yyyy-MM-dd" bs-datepicker>
```

[image]

Comment: This is all explained in the [docs](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/i18n.html)

Answer (score 0):

Further @Matheno comment you can do this by creating "language" object.

Something like:

```js
$.fn.datepicker.dates['en'] = {
  days: ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"],
  daysShort: ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"],
  daysMin: ["Su", "Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa"],
  months: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
  monthsShort: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
  today: "Today",
  clear: "Clear",
  format: "mm/dd/yyyy",
  titleFormat: "MM yyyy", /* Leverages same syntax as 'format' */
  weekStart: 0
};
```

Specific, for `kr` you can use the below script.

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.0/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.kr.min.js
```

1. Add this script to your page.
2. Set the language when you init the plugin

```js
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
  language: 'kr'
});
```

**Angular**

For the specific directive `bs-datepicker` you can add this option in the `.config` section.

Something like this:

```js
angular.module('myApp')
.config(function($datepickerProvider) {
  angular.extend($datepickerProvider.defaults, {
    language: 'kr'
  });
})
```